# New XML creation using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an input XML message that I am trying to tranform into a different XML altogether with the values taken from the input. Can you please look into it and guide me with a sample XSLT?

Input XML:

```
<Req_IN>

  <ReqID_IN>REQIDIN001</ReqID_IN>
  <ReqType_IN>AZZ002</ReqType_IN>
  <VMID_IN>VMIDINV003</VMID_IN>
  <PSMID_IN>PSMIDIN004</PSMID_IN>
  <SIDHIQ_IN>sssiiidddd54005</SIDHIQ_IN>
  <SIP_IN>SIP_IN_10.20.30.40</SIP_IN>
  <MPass_IN>full details of buyer</MPass_IN>
  <currency_IN>USD</currency_IN>
  <amt_IN>167.78</amt_IN>

  <MIDets_IN>
    <itCode_IN>a</itCode_IN>
    <itDesc_IN>aadesc</itDesc_IN> 
    <itUntprice_IN>555</itUntprice_IN>
    <itQuan_IN>41</itQuan_IN>
  </MIDets_IN>

  <MIDets_IN>
    <itCode_IN>b</itCode_IN>
    <itDesc_IN>bbbdesc</itDesc_IN> 
    <itUntprice_IN>44343</itUntprice_IN>
    <itQuan_IN>32</itQuan_IN>
  </MIDets_IN>

  <MIDets_IN>
    <itCode_IN>c</itCode_IN>
    <itDesc_IN>abcdesc</itDesc_IN> 
    <itUntprice_IN>8979</itUntprice_IN>
    <itQuan_IN>32</itQuan_IN>
  </MIDets_IN>

  <ConBDetails_IN>
    <cname_IN>firstname lastname</cname_IN>
    <ConAddress1>ConBDetails addressline1 </ConAddress1>
    <ConAddress2>ConBDetails addressline2</ConAddress2>
    <ConAddress3>ConBDetails addressline3</ConAddress3>
    <City_IN>ConBdetails_city</City_IN>
    <pcode_IN>ConBdetails_PIN</pcode_IN>
    <c_IN>ConBdetails US</c_IN>
  </ConBDetails_IN>

  <mShipDets_IN>
    <FullName>fname lname</FullName>
    <MerAddress1>mShip addressline1</MerAddress1>
    <MerAddress2>mShip addressline2</MerAddress2>
    <MerAddress3>mShip addressline3</MerAddress3>
    <City_IN>mShip city</City_IN>
    <pcode_IN>mShip PIN</pcode_IN>
    <c_IN>mSHIP US</c_IN>
  </mShipDets_IN>

  <VmeTransactionIdentifier>
    <VMeUniqueId> a9001</VMeUniqueId> 
    <AuthenticationMethod>01</AuthenticationMethod>
    <AuthenticationReasonCode>1C</AuthenticationReasonCode>
  </VmeTransactionIdentifier>

</Req_IN>
```

Output XML:

```
<Req_IN_new>

  <PSMID_IN_new>value of PSMID_IN element(PSMIDIN004)</PSMID_IN_new>
  <ReqID_IN_new>value of ReqID_IN element (REQIDIN001)</ReqID_IN_new>
  <SPT_new>value of ReqID_IN element (REQIDIN001)</SPT_new>

  <ConBDetails_IN_new>
    <cname_IN_new>firstname lastname</cname_IN_new>
    <street1>ConBDetails addressline1 </street1>
    <street2>ConBDetails addressline2 </street2>
    <street3>ConBDetails addressline3</street3>
    <city>ConBdetails_city</city>
    <postalCode>ConBdetails_PIN</postalCode>
    <country>ConBdetails_US</country>
    <ipAddress>value of SIP_IN element (SIP_IN_10.20.30.40)</ipAddress>
  </ConBDetails_IN_new>

  <MPass_IN_new>full details of buyer </MPass_IN_new>

  <mShipDets_IN_new>
    <FullName_new>fname lname</FullName_new>
    <MerAddress1_new>mShip addressline1</MerAddress1_new>
    <MerAddress2_new>mShip addressline2</MerAddress2_new>
    <MerAddress3_new>mShip addressline3</MerAddress3_new>
    <City_IN_new>mShip city</City_IN_new>
    <pcode_IN_new>mShip PIN</pcode_IN_new>
    <c_IN_new>mSHIP US</c_IN_new>
  </mShipDets_IN_new>

  <MIDets_IN_new id="0">
    <itCode_IN_new>a</itCode_IN_new>
    <itDesc_IN_new>aadesc</itDesc_IN_new> 
    <itUntprice_IN_new>555</itUntprice_IN_new>
    <itQuan_IN_new>41</itQuan_IN_new>
  </MIDets_IN_new>

  <MIDets_IN_new id="1">
    <itCode_IN_new>b</itCode_IN_new>
    <itDesc_IN_new>bbbdesc</itDesc_IN_new> 
    <itUntprice_IN_new>44343</itUntprice_IN_new>
    <itQuan_IN_new>32</itQuan_IN_new>
  </MIDets_IN_new>

  <MIDets_IN_new id="2">
    <itCode_IN_new>c</itCode_IN_new>
    <itDesc_IN_new>abcdesc</itDesc_IN_new> 
    <itUntprice_IN_new>8979</itUntprice_IN_new>
    <itQuan_IN_new>41</itQuan_IN_new>
  </MIDets_IN_new>

  <totalAmt>
    <amt_IN_new>167.78</amt_IN_new>
    <currency_IN_new>USD</currency_IN_new>
  </totalAmt>

</Req_IN_new>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This transform will do what you ask. Essentially the template for the root element picks out the elements from the source in the order they are to appear in the output, then a general-purpose template copies each element, adding `_new` to the name.

A number of other templates processes those elements that are to be handled differently from the rest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Req_IN">
    <Req_IN_new>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="PSMID_IN"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ReqID_IN"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ConBDetails_IN"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="MPass_IN"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="mShipDets_IN"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="MIDets_IN"/>
      <totalAmt>
        <amt_IN_new>
          <xsl:value-of select="amt_IN"/>
        </amt_IN_new>
        <currency_IN_new>
          <xsl:value-of select="currency_IN"/>
        </currency_IN_new>
      </totalAmt>
    </Req_IN_new>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{concat(name(), '_new')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ReqID_IN">
    <xsl:element name="{concat(name(), '_new')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
    <SPT_new>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </SPT_new>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ConBDetails_IN">
    <xsl:element name="{concat(name(), '_new')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <ipAddress>
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::SIP_IN"/>
      </ipAddress>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ConBDetails_IN/*[starts-with(name(),'ConAddress')]">
    <xsl:element name="{concat('street', substring-after(name(), 'ConAddress'))}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ConBDetails_IN/City_IN">
    <city>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </city>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ConBDetails_IN/pcode_IN">
    <postalCode>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </postalCode>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ConBDetails_IN/c_IN">
    <country>
      <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
    </country>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="MIDets_IN">
    <xsl:element name="{concat(name(), '_new')}">
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="position()-1"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<Req_IN_new>
   <PSMID_IN_new>PSMIDIN004</PSMID_IN_new>
   <ReqID_IN_new>REQIDIN001</ReqID_IN_new>
   <SPT_new>REQIDIN001</SPT_new>
   <ConBDetails_IN_new>
      <cname_IN_new>firstname lastname</cname_IN_new>
      <street1>ConBDetails addressline1 </street1>
      <street2>ConBDetails addressline2</street2>
      <street3>ConBDetails addressline3</street3>
      <city>ConBdetails_city</city>
      <postalCode>ConBdetails_PIN</postalCode>
      <country>ConBdetails US</country>
      <ipAddress>SIP_IN_10.20.30.40</ipAddress>
   </ConBDetails_IN_new>
   <MPass_IN_new>full details of buyer</MPass_IN_new>
   <mShipDets_IN_new>
      <FullName_new>fname lname</FullName_new>
      <MerAddress1_new>mShip addressline1</MerAddress1_new>
      <MerAddress2_new>mShip addressline2</MerAddress2_new>
      <MerAddress3_new>mShip addressline3</MerAddress3_new>
      <City_IN_new>mShip city</City_IN_new>
      <pcode_IN_new>mShip PIN</pcode_IN_new>
      <c_IN_new>mSHIP US</c_IN_new>
   </mShipDets_IN_new>
   <MIDets_IN_new id="0">
      <itCode_IN_new>a</itCode_IN_new>
      <itDesc_IN_new>aadesc</itDesc_IN_new>
      <itUntprice_IN_new>555</itUntprice_IN_new>
      <itQuan_IN_new>41</itQuan_IN_new>
   </MIDets_IN_new>
   <MIDets_IN_new id="1">
      <itCode_IN_new>b</itCode_IN_new>
      <itDesc_IN_new>bbbdesc</itDesc_IN_new>
      <itUntprice_IN_new>44343</itUntprice_IN_new>
      <itQuan_IN_new>32</itQuan_IN_new>
   </MIDets_IN_new>
   <MIDets_IN_new id="2">
      <itCode_IN_new>c</itCode_IN_new>
      <itDesc_IN_new>abcdesc</itDesc_IN_new>
      <itUntprice_IN_new>8979</itUntprice_IN_new>
      <itQuan_IN_new>32</itQuan_IN_new>
   </MIDets_IN_new>
   <totalAmt>
      <amt_IN_new>167.78</amt_IN_new>
      <currency_IN_new>USD</currency_IN_new>
   </totalAmt>
</Req_IN_new>
```

Comment: Borodin, thanks for your quick response. Tested your xslt and working perfectly. Is it possible to create output xml elements independent of input elements, i mean the output XML elements should not be derived from input xml with '_new' suffix. These output xml elements should construct by giving fullname as per output xml.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to iterate through your XML elements using XSL elements such as `xsl:template`, `xsl_value-of` and `xsl:apply-templates`. I shan't do it for you but here is a typical snippet:

```
<xsl:template match="ConAddress1">
    <street1><xsl:value-of select="."/></street1>
</xsl:template>
```

Here you are converting from one element name, selecting its content and creating a new element (`street1`). Your XSL could contain about 30 templates.

If you look at any tutorials they'll have many examples of this type of conversion.